# how to read sqlite db file in unity

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have tried to read SQLite DB file in unity project. When I run the application in mac, DB files read successfully but when running the application in windows I am getting shared violation exception. Please suggest any idea to read SQLite DB file in windows. Here is the code I am using for reading SQLite DB file.

### Sample code :

```
string dbPath = "C:/Users/test12/AppData/LocalLow/test Solutions Ltd/testapp/testdb.db";

dbPath = Path.GetFullPath(dbPath);
var dbData = File.ReadAllBytes(dbPath);
```

In above code getting the exception in file.readallbytes()line.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by reading this db file?

Comment: I need to get bytes by reading this files. I have a requirement of sending this DB file to the email. Here I am sending DB files data to my API in the form of bytes.

Comment: Check the `Type` of file in window explorer. It should work for all type of extensions if you remove `.db` from your path.

Comment: sorry. I didn't get what you are trying to say. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: Change your path to `C:/Users/test12/AppData/LocalLow/test Solutions Ltd/testapp/testdb`.

Comment: I have removed .db extension from file path and run the application but I am getting could not find a part of the path error.

Comment: Close any other applications that are reading the db file.

Comment: I have tried that one also, still getting same issue. Same code running without exceptions in mac but in windows only getting this issue.